# What URI do I need on the browser side to connect to an amazon redis server from heroku's redis addon

Tags: laravel, heroku, redis, socket.io, ioredis

I'm trying to set up a chat application on heroku with redis and socket.io, but I can't figure out what uri am I suppose to put on the client side.

All uri's I have tried, give me a 404, name_not_resolved, or timeout erorrs.

---

I have one heroku app, which is running a node.js buildpack, and all it does is runs the socket.js file.

And I have another php heroku app which has the laravel back end with redis broadcasting and a vue front end.

---

The broadcasting is set up so that when someone publishes a post or makes a GET request of '/', an event is fired on 'new-post-channell' and 'user-entered-chat-channel' respectively.

---

I can go into the bash of the socket.js app and run 'node socket.js'. I can see that it connects to heroku's redis addon Amazon server and picks up on the broadcasts.

I can also go into the heroku's redis-cli of the second app, into the monitor mode, and see that broadcasts are being picked up as intended.

---

It all worked in a vagrant homestead virtual server, but doesn't on heroku.

```
var socket = io('redis://h:oaisuhaosiufhasodiufh@ec2-99-81-167-43.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:6639');
```

(and maybe you also know how can I run the 'node socket.js' command on my first app automatically, so that I wouldn't have to go into the heroku's bash and run it manually?)

Comment: If those are your real credentials you should invalidate them **_immediately_**. They are forever compromised, and you need to generate new ones. Editing them out of your question is _**not enough**_.

Comment: No. Not real. What's the worst that could happen if they were real and if it's just a learning app?

Answer (score 0):

All and all.. I finally got a VPS on Vultr.com.. And ran into the same problem..

So the answer is

1. if you have https done.. then you need to put the domain you are on.

```
io('https://'+ window.location.hostname, {reconnect: true});
```

2. You need to navigate to your nginx configuration files and edit them.. I've set up mine in the sites-available section.

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/yourDomainOrIp.conf
```

3.
You will have these sections "location" in the configuration file. Make a new one. I put mine before the others.

```
        location /socket.io/ {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_pass "http://localhost:3000/socket.io/";
        }
```

this section means if you visit something /socket.io/ it will be redirected to localhost port 3000.
And on local host port 3000 I have the nodejs app listening

```
var server = require('http').Server();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redisNewMessage = new Redis();
var redisUserEntered = new Redis();
server.listen(3000);
```

Soo.. I still don't know how to fully answer the question.. but basically:

in that io() you would need to pass an address which eventually passes the "/socket.io/polling%something&something" to the localhost and the port of the server in which nodejs app is sitting in.

That amazon link stays in the nodejs new Redis ().. Socket.io has to connect to the nodejs app file and then it all should work.